# MbUnit's row attribute in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

While reading an Asp.Net MVC code sample that used MbUnit as its testing framework, I saw that it was possible to run a single test against multiple input possibilities by using a Row attribute, like so:

```
[Test]
[Row("test@test_test.com")]
[Row("sdfdf dsfsdf")]
[Row("sdfdf@.com")]
public void Invalid_Emails_Should_Return_False(string invalidEmail)
{
    ...
}
```

Please I'd like to know if there is a Visual Studio 2010 equivalent of MbUnit's Row attribute, or otherwise an elegant way to achieve this in Visual Studio 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"[How to: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspxBlockquote)" (MSDN)

Comment: Data driven Test is different. Is their any simple approach